A distance and an open ball topology on the ring of quaternions
On the ring $\mathbb H$ of quaternions $q$, can we regard
$$
d(q_1,\,q_2) = \sqrt{(q_2-q_1)^*\, (q_2-q_1)\,}
$$
as a distance, and utilise it to build an open ball topology?

If you identify $\mathbb H\cong \mathbb R^4$, this is just the Euclidean norm, so yes

@JohannesMoerland I appreciate your help.
